# Difference of two sets and distributivity

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A,B,C$ are sets, then we all know that $A\setminus (B\cap C)= (A\setminus B)\cup (A\setminus C)$. So by induction 
$$A\setminus\bigcap_{i=1}^nB_i=\bigcup_{i=1}^n (A\setminus B_i)$$
for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Now if $I$ is an uncountable set and $\{B_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a family of sets, is it true that:
$$A\setminus\bigcap_{i\in I}B_i=\bigcup_{i\in I} (A\setminus B_i)\,\,\,?$$

If the answer to the above question will be "NO", what can we say if $I$ is countable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  If $x$ is in the left hand side then it's in $A$ but not in $\bigcap_{i\in I} B_i$, so it's missing from one of the $B_i$'s. Therefore it's in $A \setminus B_i$ for some $B_i$, and it's in the right hand side.  The other direction is similar.

Answer (score 2):

De Morgan's laws are most fundamental and hold for all indexed families, no matter the cardinalities involved. So, $$A-\bigcap _{i\in I}A_i=\bigcup _{i\in I}(A-A_i)$$ and dually $$A-\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i=\bigcap _{i\in I}(A-A_i).$$ The proof is a very good exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
A\setminus \bigcap_{i\in I}B_i=A\cap \left(\bigcap_{i\in I}B_i\right)^c,
$$
where $^c$ denotes the complement. Using [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) (which holds for a general $I$) we get
$$
A\cap \left(\bigcap_{i\in I}B_i\right)^c =A\cap \left(\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i^c\right)=\bigcup_{i \in I}\left(A\cap B_i^c\right).
$$
Now note that $A\cap B_i^c =A\setminus B_i$ and we are done.